# Why is this iframe height stuck at 150 px?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Here is the entire file.  I thought it might be a reset issue so I set height to 100% for both the body and the iframe. View here - www.arcmarks.com/video.  Please do not repost.

I want it to take up the entire page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        .if {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <iframe class="if" name="result" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals"
            frameborder="0" src="//fiddle.jshell.net/kizu/zfUyN/show/"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like that iframe called another iframe ...

Comment: html 100% works, please stop submitting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` and `html` are of full width only. It is by jsfiddle.net, your view is limited to a height of `148px`. Please check below:

[image]

**Solution**

Since you cannot control `jsfiddle.net`, having `html, body {height: 100%;}` also might work. Please try checking with the API to get the full width. There's an option to share full screen embed. Please try that.

Comment: can you please remove the part of the image that has my domain on it.

Comment: @cadegalt Yes I can, but you already have given out in the question, isn't it? **Deleted the part**

Comment: @cadegalt **I have removed after you said.** Can't you see? But the domain is still there in your question. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `html { height: 100%; }` to your CSS.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1fx9jnx/)

Here's the explanation:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: Kindly check my answer. Do you agree with mine? The height is not limited by the HTML. The OP has given right code, but the problem lies within the other domain.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  Yes, I see your answer. But the OP has stated in question comments and your answer comments that *html 100%* works. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` in css of the iframe.

```
.if {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%
  width:100%
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the CSS of another domain.

Comment: What are you trying to say? i meant the element with `if` class.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/02bcw1jn/)

For the `iframe` to take `100%` height, you need to set the height of `html` along with `body` to `100%`.

Thus the updated CSS would be as below

**CSS**

```
html,body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

As a note, you have to mention the `<style>` inside the `<head>` tag and not inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Removed the downvote. Your's doesn't answer the question. No use putting that CSS. It is limited by jsfiddle in the demo. Have a look please.

Comment: Please kindly have a look at my answer, as this doesn't work. Already the OP's code has the full height DOM.

Comment: Saw your answer..but, the OP himself has mentioned in his comments that giving `100%` to `html` worked @PraveenKumar